# Error in R - more columns than column names

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to read in a file that has 5 column headers, however in column 5 I have list of genes separated commas.

```
EC2 <- read.table("david.txt",  header=TRUE)
```

Whenever I run the code below, I get the message

```
"more columns than column names."
```

I feel like the answer is probably simple. Any idea?

These are the first 3 lines:

```
Category ID Term PValue Genes
BP GO: 0006412 translation 2.711930356491234E-10 P0A7U3, P0A7K6, P68191, P0A7Q1, P0A7U7, P02359, P02358, P60438, P0A7L0, P0A7L3, P0A7L8, P0A7T3, P0A8A8, P69441, P0A8N5, P0A8N3, P02413, P0A7T7, P0AG63, P0A7D1, P0AA10 , P0ADY3, P0AG67, P0A7M2, P0A898, P0A9W3, P0A7M6, P0A7X3, P0AAR3, P0A7S3, P0A7S9, P0ADY7, P62399, P60624, P32132, P0ADZ4, P60723, P0C0U4, P0AG51, P0ADZ0, P0A7N9, P0A7J3, P0A7W7, P0AG59, P68679, P0C018 , P0A7R1, P0A7N4, P0A7R5, P0A7R9, P0AG44, P68919, P61175, P0A6K3, P0A7V0, P0A7M9, P0A7K2, P0A7V3, P0AG48
BP GO: 0051301 cell division 1.4011247561051483E-7 P0AC30, P17952, P75949, P0A6H1, P06966, P0A9R7, P64612, P36548, P60472, P45955, P0A855, P06136, P0A850, P6246, P0246, P024 P22523, P08373, P11880, P0AFB1, P60293, P18196, P0ABG4, P07026, P0A749, P29131, P0A6S5, P26648, P17443, P0ADS2, P0A8P6, P0A8P8, P0A6, P0A6A7, P0A8P8, P0A6, P0A6A7, P0A6, P0A6A7 P46889, P0A6F9, P0AE60, P0AD68, P19934, P0ABU9, P37773
```

Comment: It seems that your real separator character is a space rather than a comma. Try setting `sep = " "`. Still there will be a problem because the list of genes also had a space character in between.

Comment: Your cells should be quoted since they have a space inside them, otherwise they will be treated as different columns instead of one

Comment: Maybe your best option is to read line by line and separate the 5 columns by code. There are spaces everywhere and who created this file should not have used a space as a delimiter.

Comment: Yes, there is the same problem.

Comment: Go back to the person who created this file and ask them to either quote text or use a different delimiter.

Comment: I am guessing the separator is a TAB, try this: `EC2 <- read.table("david.txt",  header = TRUE,`sep = "\t")`